# Debian 8(Jessie): netbios name resolution

Tags: networking, debian, samba, netbios

To resolve netbios names on Debian 7(Wheezy) I used to install winbind and append a 'wins' in /etc/nsswitch.conf. This procedure appears to not work on a freshly installed Debian 8.2(Jessie). It does, however, work on a Debian Jessie upgraded from Debian Wheezy.

So is there anything wrong with Jessie or is it that I am missing something? How does one go about enabling netbios name resolution in Jessie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I managed to fix it by installing package libnss-winbind.